# What extensions work with jQuery validate extension function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have the following code setup for a form using jQuery validate plugin (I cut out uneeded code).

```
$("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        attachment: {extension: "txt|rtf|jpg|jpeg|png|pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|bmp|tif"}
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        return false;
    },
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        if(this.numberOfInvalids() > 0 && errorList.length > 0) {
            if($(errorList[0].element).attr("id") == "attachment") {
                displayModStatusMessage(false, errorList[0].message, $("#modResponse"), false, 505); 
            }
            else { displayModStatusMessage(false, errorList[0].message, $("#modResponse"), false); }
        }
        else if(this.numberOfInvalids() == 0) { removeMessage($("#modResponse")); }
    }
});
```

For some reason though, if I go and try to add an attachment with a .txt ending, or .doc ending, the error message is showing up. It is working with .png.

Here is the important html

```
<tr>
    <td class="textright"><label for="attachment">Attach:</label></td>
    <td class="textleft"><input type="file" id="attachment" name="attachment" value="" accept=".txt, .rtf, .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .pdf, .doc, .docx, .xls, .xlsx, .ppt, .pptx, .bmp, .tif" /></td>
</tr>
```

I should add that I am using the latest version of jQuery validate (1.14.0) and the latest version of the additional methods (1.14.0).

Comment: Show the relevant HTML for this.

Comment: @sparky Sorry, when I try to do a .png the error message does not show up, which is correct.

Comment: You are missing a comma right after your `rules` object.  Other than that, I cannot reproduce your issue in a jsFiddle.

Comment: Please post your HTML form. Are you sure you have input field with `id="attachment"`. It works for png because png, jpeg and gif are default rules, which means your rules are not being applied. There is a disconnect somewhere...

Comment: @Beginner, the `extension` method is already part of the plugin in the `additional-methods.js` file.  See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/extension-method/

Comment: Ok, that's two of us now asking you to post the relevant HTML.

Comment: @Zealander you may be onto something. When I get home I will look at it and post more. But the html element is definitely there, or png still would not work.

Comment: @Zealander, correction... it's **NOT** the `id`... the plugin only uses the `name` attribute.  He needs `name="attachment"`.

Comment: I'm sure it's correct but I will look.

Comment: @Zealander I am wondering if this is something to do with the fact that its a file input. Maybe it is trying to check the file name before the file name is actually present. I am about to test out that theory.

Comment: @Sparky Does the validate plugin look inside at the file contents? Or strictly the name?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89302/discussion-between-metropolis-and-sparky).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `accept` attribute within the HTML.  This is picked up and used by the jQuery Validate plugin's corresponding [`accept` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/accept-method/).

```
<input accept=".txt, .rtf, .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .pdf, .doc, .docx, .xls, .xlsx, .ppt, .pptx, .bmp, .tif" ... />
```

By using it, you're effectively applying both the `accept` and `extension` methods to validate file extensions.  HOWEVER, in jQuery Validate, the `accept` method is only used for validating MIME types.

Remove the `accept` attribute entirely.